# looping JSON in node JS with no ARRAY

Tags: javascript, json

I have a response from API where JSON is not in an array, something like below

```
{
  "TV": {
    "USD": 9677.25,
    "EUR": 7768.87,
    "JPY": 1072773.87,
    "GBP": 6898.93,
    "AUD": 12294.15,
    "CAD": 12056.19
},
 "Lamp": {
    "USD": 231.35,
    "EUR": 185.89,
    "JPY": 25735.85,
    "GBP": 168.82,
    "AUD": 296.7,
    "CAD": 283
  }
}
```

if it is array I can use `.map` function, but in this scenario how can I display data while looping it as data coming from API might be  different on every call.

desired format that i am looking for is

```
[{
    "PRODUCT": "TV",
    "PRICE": {
        "USD": 9677.25,
        "EUR": 7768.87,
        "JPY": 1072773.87,
        "GBP": 6898.93,
        "AUD": 12294.15,
        "CAD": 12056.19
    }
}, {
    "PRODUCT": "Lamp",
    "PRICE": {
        "USD": 231.35,
        "EUR": 185.89,
        "JPY": 25735.85,
        "GBP": 168.82,
        "AUD": 296.7,
        "CAD": 283
    }
}]
```

Please help..

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: @HassanImam I want to convert above mention JSON to array

Comment: Please update the question with the desired format.

Comment: @HassanImam updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Object.keys()` to iterate through each key of your data and then using `array#map`, you can create a resultant array with your objects.

```js
var data = { "TV": { "USD": 9677.25, "EUR": 7768.87, "JPY": 1072773.87, "GBP": 6898.93, "AUD": 12294.15, "CAD": 12056.19 }, "Lamp": { "USD": 231.35, "EUR": 185.89, "JPY": 25735.85, "GBP": 168.82, "AUD": 296.7, "CAD": 283 } },
  result = Object.keys(data).map(k => ({PRODUCT: k, PRICE: data[k]}));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the keys for the top level properties of the JSON object.

```
var payload = {
  "TV": {
    "USD": 9677.25,
    "EUR": 7768.87,
    "JPY": 1072773.87,
    "GBP": 6898.93,
    "AUD": 12294.15,
    "CAD": 12056.19
},
 "Lamp": {
    "USD": 231.35,
    "EUR": 185.89,
    "JPY": 25735.85,
    "GBP": 168.82,
    "AUD": 296.7,
    "CAD": 283
  }
}

var keys = Object.keys(payload)
```

Now you can map over these keys and use them to reference the payload. So for example if you wanted to create an array with the USD cost of each item.

```
var usdCost = keys.map(function (key) {
  return {
    item: key,
    usd: payload[key].USD
  }
})

// [{
//   item: "TV",
//   usd: 9677.25
// }, {
//   item: "Lamp",
//   usd: 231.35
// }]
```